# Javascript: Dynamic Check box (Fieldset with Father/Child Checkboxes)

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, checkbox, prototypejs

I have a problem here, when I select any of the 'father' checkboxes all the child checkboxes are getting enabled or disabled. So I need each father checkbox to affect it own child fieldset. Could someone help me with this.

Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>toggle disabled</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
.cssDisabled { color: #ccc; }
</style>

<script src="http://prototypejs.org/assets/2009/8/31/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe(window, 'load', function(){
    // for all items in the group_first class
    $$('.father').each(function(chk1){
        // watch for clicks
        chk1.observe('click', function(evt){
            dynamicCheckbox();
        });
    dynamicCheckbox();
    });
});
function dynamicCheckbox (){
    // count how many of group_first are checked,
            // doEnable true if any are checked
    var doEnable = ($$('.father:checked').length > 0) ? true : false;
    // for each in group_second, enable the checkbox, and
            // remove the cssDisabled class from the parent label
    $$('.child').each(function(item){
        if (doEnable) {
            item.enable().up('label').removeClassName('cssDisabled');
        } else {
            item.disable().up('label').addClassName('cssDisabled');
        }
    });
};
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>First Group</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="father" />Check box 1</label><br />
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="2" class="father" checked/>Check box 2</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Second Group</legend>
    <label class="cssDisabled"><input type="checkbox" value="x" class="child" disabled="disabled" />Check box x</label><br />
    <label class="cssDisabled"><input type="checkbox" value="y" class="child" disabled="disabled" />Check box y</label><br />
    <label class="cssDisabled"><input type="checkbox" value="z" class="child" disabled="disabled" />Check box z</label>
</fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>First Group</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="3" class="father" />Check box 1</label><br />
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Second Group</legend>
    <label class="cssDisabled"><input type="checkbox" value="x" class="child" disabled="disabled" />Check box x</label><br />
    <label class="cssDisabled"><input type="checkbox" value="y" class="child" disabled="disabled" />Check box y</label><br />
    <label class="cssDisabled"><input type="checkbox" value="z" class="child" disabled="disabled" />Check box z</label>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what functionality you're wanting but if you only want actions to apply to one set then give each set their own class maybe something like father1 and child1 and father2 and child2

Comment: Maybe, but there is where I'm stucked, I want to do the JS code dynamic, to automatically check the father and child ids and link them. Adding an Id number to the classes it's a good idea. If someone would show me a short example, would help me, thanks.

Comment: If you used jQuery instead of prototype.js, you would have gotten tons of answers by now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of the affect you want, but here are the broad rules. You need something in your HTML to tell your js which should affect which. Attributes are best, either `rel` or `id` or, simplest, `class`.

So, give each `.father` an ID that's unique to it among `.father`s.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="father" id="foo">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="father" id="bar">
```

Then give the children corresponding/identical classes.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="child foo">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="child bar">
```

(By the way, you're not using XHTML, so you don't need the trailing slashes.)

I don't know Prototype, but what you then need to do is, for each `.father`, grab the `id` (`#foo` and `#bar` above) and look for all checkboxes with classes `.child` *and* either `.foo` or `.bar`, depending. (You can pull off that last bit by storing the `id` to a variable, and altering the text to add on the period and make it a class.)

Comment: Can you write any example here?